# JavaScript Dynamic onClick problem

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to give a button an onclick event when a certain thing on a page changes. I have tried to do it many different ways and none have worked. What am I doing wrong?

Below are what I have tried.

```
document.getElementById(subDiv).onclick = function() { alert('Error. There is an error on the the page. Please correct that then submit the page'); };


document.getElementById(subDiv).onclick = "alert('Error. There is an error on the the page. Please correct that then submit the page');";


function redErrorAlert()
{
    alert('Error. There is an error on the the page. Please correct that then submit the page');
}
document.getElementById(subDiv).onclick = redErrorAlert;



document.getElementById(subDiv).setAttribute('onclick',redErrorAlert(), false);



document.getElementById(subDiv).setAttribute('onclick','redErrorAlert()', false);
```

Note: subDiv is a variable containing the id of the element.

Comment: You really should consider using a js library like jquery as it makes this a lot easier and cross browser compliant. That said..

What browser are you trying to test this in?

Comment: @spinon I am testing in Chrome, but it needs to work in IE, FF and Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like jQuery territory here. Once you learn the ins and outs of jQuery, things like this are a snap to take care of, and you'll find yourself writing a lot less JavaScript.

First, get jQuery from http://jquery.com/

Then put this in your code to bind the event:

```
$('#idOfElementToBindClickEvent').click(function(){
  alert('Error.');
});
```

jQuery basically provides a way to manipulate elements using CSS-like selectors.

Answer (score 2):

You need to wait for the DOM tree to be created before you do queries on it.

Make sure that this all happens within a context that is created **after** the DOM tree has been built:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById(subDiv).onclick = function() { alert('Error. There is an error on the the page. Please correct that then submit the page'); };
};
```

Comment: The page as already been loaded when this is called. The function that makes the call is only called when an input box changes and does not validate. The DOM tree should already be loaded at this point, should it not?

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById() takes a string containing the ID of the element you're trying to find. Assuming you're looking for the element with id 'subDiv', you should be calling document.getElementById('subDiv').

(It's also possible that the variable subDiv in your code is a string containing the ID, but since you didn't mention it I'm assuming that it doesn't.)

**EDIT:** If you were to go with virstulte's suggestion of using jQuery, you'd attach a function to the document.ready event in order to ensure that the DOM has been built by the time your code runs. Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#subDiv").click(function() { alert("Test!"); });
});
```

Comment: subDiv is a variable containing the id. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ah, then it's like Jacob said -- the DOM hasn't initialized yet. I'd also consider virstulte's excellent suggestion of checking out jQuery. I've edited my answer to combine Jacob and virstulte's code.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
document.getElementById(subDiv).onclick = alert('Error. There is an error on the the page. Please correct that then submit the page');
```

or

```
function redAlert() {
    alert('Error. There is an error on the the page. Please correct that then submit the page');
}

document.getElementById(subDiv).onclick = redAlert();
```

First case: you need to call the function, and you've assigned a string

Second case: you've assigned a function and you were not calling this function